# Laravel: Class 'App\Http\Requests\Api\BaseFormRequest' not found when I run tests

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I am getting this error whenever I run my tests.`BaseFormRequest` is base class for all the `FormRequest` class in my app which handles JSON response as per my need. All the tests were running fine few days ago.
I had to do a clean OS install. After setting up my OS. I pulled all my projects from BitBucket. install the dependencies in this Laravel project but when starting running tests it started giving me this weird error.
Here is the response dump from the test.

```
#3159
  +"message": "Class 'App\Http\Requests\Api\BaseFormRequest' not found"
  +"exception": "Error"
  +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/app/Http/Requests/StoreTeacherAttendanceRequest.php"
  +"line": 7
  +"trace": array:49 [
    0 => {#3320
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php"
      +"line": 444
      +"function": "include"
    }
    1 => {#3458
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php"
      +"line": 322
      +"function": "Composer\Autoload\includeFile"
    }
    2 => {#3617
      +"function": "loadClass"
      +"class": "Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    3 => {#3161
      +"function": "spl_autoload_call"
    }
    4 => {#3457
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Reflector.php"
      +"line": 50
      +"function": "class_exists"
    }
    5 => {#1624
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteSignatureParameters.php"
      +"line": 26
      +"function": "isParameterSubclassOf"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Support\Reflector"
      +"type": "::"
    }
    6 => {#3319
      +"function": "Illuminate\Routing\{closure}"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Routing\RouteSignatureParameters"
      +"type": "::"
    }
    7 => {#56
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteSignatureParameters.php"
      +"line": 27
      +"function": "array_filter"
    }
    8 => {#3322
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php"
      +"line": 491
      +"function": "fromAction"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Routing\RouteSignatureParameters"
      +"type": "::"
    }
    9 => {#53
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ImplicitRouteBinding.php"
      +"line": 25
      +"function": "signatureParameters"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Route"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    10 => {#49
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
      +"line": 798
      +"function": "resolveForRoute"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Routing\ImplicitRouteBinding"
      +"type": "::"
    }
    11 => {#57
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php"
      +"line": 39
      +"function": "substituteImplicitBindings"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    12 => {#55
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      +"line": 167
      +"function": "handle"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    13 => {#47
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php"
      +"line": 59
      +"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    14 => {#3619
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      +"line": 167
      +"function": "handle"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    15 => {#3164
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php"
      +"line": 44
      +"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    16 => {#3616
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      +"line": 167
      +"function": "handle"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    17 => {#3461
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      +"line": 103
      +"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    18 => {#3618
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
      +"line": 687
      +"function": "then"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    19 => {#3622
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
      +"line": 662
      +"function": "runRouteWithinStack"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    20 => {#3475
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
      +"line": 628
      +"function": "runRoute"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    21 => {#3335
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
      +"line": 617
      +"function": "dispatchToRoute"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    22 => {#3177
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php"
      +"line": 165
      +"function": "dispatch"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    23 => {#3632
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      +"line": 128
      +"function": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    24 => {#3474
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php"
      +"line": 21
      +"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    25 => {#3334
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      +"line": 167
      +"function": "handle"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    26 => {#3176
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php"
      +"line": 21
      +"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    27 => {#3336
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      +"line": 167
      +"function": "handle"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    28 => {#3179
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php"
      +"line": 27
      +"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    29 => {#3337
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      +"line": 167
      +"function": "handle"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    30 => {#3634
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php"
      +"line": 63
      +"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    31 => {#3456
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      +"line": 167
      +"function": "handle"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    32 => {#3339
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php"
      +"line": 57
      +"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    33 => {#3182
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      +"line": 167
      +"function": "handle"
      +"class": "Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    34 => {#3340
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php"
      +"line": 103
      +"function": "Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    35 => {#3480
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php"
      +"line": 140
      +"function": "then"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    36 => {#3638
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php"
      +"line": 109
      +"function": "sendRequestThroughRouter"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    37 => {#3183
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php"
      +"line": 508
      +"function": "handle"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    38 => {#3341
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php"
      +"line": 474
      +"function": "call"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    39 => {#3481
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/tests/Feature/TeacherAttendanceManagementTest.php"
      +"line": 48
      +"function": "json"
      +"class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    40 => {#3639
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php"
      +"line": 1415
      +"function": "test_teacher_attendance_can_be_taken"
      +"class": "Tests\Feature\TeacherAttendanceManagementTest"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    41 => {#3184
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php"
      +"line": 1035
      +"function": "runTest"
      +"class": "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    42 => {#3342
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php"
      +"line": 691
      +"function": "runBare"
      +"class": "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    43 => {#3482
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php"
      +"line": 763
      +"function": "run"
      +"class": "PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    44 => {#3640
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php"
      +"line": 597
      +"function": "run"
      +"class": "PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    45 => {#3185
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php"
      +"line": 627
      +"function": "run"
      +"class": "PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    46 => {#3343
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php"
      +"line": 204
      +"function": "doRun"
      +"class": "PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    47 => {#3483
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php"
      +"line": 163
      +"function": "run"
      +"class": "PHPUnit\TextUI\Command"
      +"type": "->"
    }
    48 => {#3641
      +"file": "/home/ropali/.local/share/Trash/files/edu_assit_api/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit"
      +"line": 61
      +"function": "main"
      +"class": "PHPUnit\TextUI\Command"
      +"type": "::"
    }
  ]
}
```

**My BaseFormRequest.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest as LaravelFormRequest;

abstract class BaseFormRequest extends LaravelFormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    abstract public function rules();

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    abstract public function authorize();

    /**
     * Handle a failed validation attempt.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        
        throw new HttpResponseException(
            response()->error($validator->messages()->all(), JsonResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
        );
    }
}
```

**My FormRequest**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Api\BaseFormRequest;


class StoreTeacherAttendanceRequest extends BaseFormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'attendance_date'  => 'required',
            'in_time'          => 'required',
            'out_time'         => 'required',
            'class'            => 'required',
            'subject'          => 'required',
            'session'          => 'required',
            'teacher_id'       => 'required',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Check if duplicate entry is being made
     */
    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        $validator->after(function ($validator) {

            $exist = \App\TeacherAttendance::where([
                'teacher_id'      => request()->teacher_id,
                'attendance_date' => request()->attendance_date,
                'in_time'         => request()->in_time,
                'out_time'        => request()->out_time
            ])->first();

            if (!empty($exist)) {
                $validator->errors()->add('duplicate_attendance', 'Duplicate attendance entry!');
            }

            
        });
    }
}
```

Actually I am getting this error for all the tests which send request to API which uses BaseFormREquest. I have tried `composer dump-autoload` few times but not luck. My APIs are working perfectly If send request from POSTMAN.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but this might be a Composer auto-loading issue. I've been getting some warnings when running `composer install` telling me something about some classes not being to be auto-loaded because `Class <XXXXXXX> does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0`. I had to fix some class names to make them work in Composer v2.0. And since you did a clean install, you might have pulled the latest Composer.

Comment: So how do I resolve it???

Comment: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/  would be a good place to start.

Comment: So I had App\Http\Requests\Api\BaseFormRequest as namespace but App\Http\RequestsBaseFormRequest as dir structure. After changing it to App\Http\Requests\Api\BaseFormRequest. i Still get the warning by composer.`Class App\Http\Requests\Api\BaseFormRequest located in ./app/Http/Requests/BaseFormRequest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.`

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload` after changing the files?

Comment: yes it is not detecting the changes i think

Comment: @tamrat Thanks for your help. For some weird reason composer was not able to detect the changes on the file from the terminal session i was using. I killed the terminal reopen it & re-run the `composer dump-autoload` and it was able to detect the changes & warning was gone.